# How to make WSO2 Auth type as "none" through store ui when we design a new rest api

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a working REST API link 
http://192.168.1.5:8080/SpringRestHibernate/student/1

I have downloaded WSO2 API Manager tool kit in same machine and wso2server.sh is running  and I am trying to hit the rest api mentioned above through api manager url.

I get the below response even if I give the correct token in API console . 
**Required OAuth credentials not provided. Make sure your API invocation call has a header: "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"**

can anyone help me out how to remove the authentication set up through UI .

[image: after making auth as none]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the api publisher when editing the API go to you Design tab (first tab) then under API Definition click on Edit Source.  In the source, each resource of your API will have an x-auth-type property, change the value to none and the API will not require authentication anymore.

Before:

```
/CheckPhoneNumber:
get:
  responses:
    '200':
      description: ''
  x-auth-type: Application & Application User
  x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
post:
  responses:
    '200':
      description: ''
  x-auth-type: Application & Application User
  x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
```

After with authentication disabled:

```
/CheckPhoneNumber:
get:
  responses:
    '200':
      description: ''
  x-auth-type: None
  x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
post:
  responses:
    '200':
      description: ''
  x-auth-type: None
  x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
```

Comment: i have updated the yaml as per your message and i get 404 response . whereas the direct url works. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Then you probably have the endpoint wrongly configured, the 404 comes from the tomcat server, not the API manager, so the API Manager is probably forwarding the  request to an incorrect endpoint. Maybe check your tomcat error log to see what the request comes in on. Also if the problem persists please create a new question on Stack Overflow instead of adding to the existing one.